# Change the post login target on FOSuserBundle Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

When I log in `/login`, I'm sent to the root url `/`, however I'd like to send users straight to another page `/dashboard` - is this a configurable option?

I'm using FOSUserBundle and Symfony2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that login is handled by SecurityBundle, not by FOSUserBundle. The solution is to put the login target here:

```
#app/config/security.yml

security:
    firewalls:
    somename:
        form_login:
            default_target_path: /your-desired-path
```

Symfony2 documentation here http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#form-login-configuration